# How to point to Entity Framework DB Context for different environments

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have 3 databases DBDev, DBStaging and DBProduction. Inside my app I have created 3 edmx for each DB. Each DB has a matching entity like so: DBDev -> DEVEntities, DBStaging -> StagingEntities or DBProduction -> ProductionEntities

I choose which DB I want to access via this in web.config:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="Configs\DBDev.config" /> <!-- or DBStaging or DBProduction-->
```

I route all of my DB access to one static class: DBAccess. When I need to point to a specific context, I manually do this:

```
private static DEVEntities db = new DEVEntities();
```

or

```
private static StagingEntities db = new StagingEntities();
```

or

```
private static ProductionEntities db = new ProductionEntities();
```

What is a more intelligent way to point to the desired context without having to manually change it?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using three different edmx?  Are the schemas different?

Comment: No, they are the same. I wanted to use the config files because each environment has different connection string values:
data source
Initial Catalog
user id
password
I didn't know how else to do it except to create different edmx. If I should only have created one edmx, how would I be able to send the values of those different values?

Comment: And why do you have static contexts? There's a 99.9% chance that this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create three different connection strings in your configuration file, like so:

   ```
   <connectionStrings>
     <add name="DevConnection" connectionString="..." />
     <add name="StagingConnection" connectionString="..." />
     <add name="ProdConnection" connectionString="..." />
   </connectionStrings>
   ```
2. In your Entity Framework context class, add a constructor that takes a connection string as parameter and calls the corresponding base constructor:

   ```
   public class MyEntities : ObjectContext // or DbContext
   {
       public MyEntities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) {}
   }
   ```
3. Instantiate your entity context by passing the name of the connection string. You could also use a dependency injection container and configure it to use the right value:

   ```
   var context = new MyEntities("DevConnection");
   ```

Comment: Don't you think that *one* connection string (and one context class) should be enough? All databases have the same schema. The connection string can be modified according to each environment.

Comment: @GertArnold you say "one connection string" but then you acknowledge the connection string would need to be "modified" for the different databses ("environment" as you say.) What are you proposing? How is it different than what Frank made? Or different than the OP?

Comment: @TheRedPea One context class and one named connection *entry* in the config file should suffice here. The connection string *value* can be changed to connect to the right database. But the question wasn't clear at all. IIRC I tried to spark some discussion to get more clarity.

Comment: Ah, one context, one config; but when you deploy your app to environment {1}, change the config to point to {1} ?

Comment: If I were to do something  like this I would set the connection string to be used in an AppSettings variable.

<AppSettings>
<add key="dbConnection" value="DevConnection" />

Then I would call the Step 3:
var context = new MyEntities(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbConnection"]);

Answer (score 1):

Another solution which is more [ALM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_lifecycle_management) compliant :

1. Create setting

   <connectionStrings>
     <add name="dbConnection" connectionString="..." ... />
   </connectionStrings>
2. In Solution Explorer expand Web.config and you will see Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config
3. Add to both

   <connectionStrings>
       <add name="dbConnection" connectionString="..." ...
         xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
   </connectionStrings>

You can add additional Web.xxx.configs. I have tried and tested this for a Azure Cloud Service project with several configurations for local debug, staging debug, production, etc and it works fine. If you are going to make Azure web app this is the recommended way to roll out new versions because when you swap your Staging/Production code, it will swap code but not your configuration.

Of course you can use this without Azure :) This is again the recommended way in order not go get lost in the configuration forest.

Another bonus is that you can right-click on the Web.xxx.config and then click 'Preview Transform' which will not only give you a preview but will also validate your configuration.